# How can I add WPF form into tab item of tab control

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

How can I add WPF form into tab item of tab control?

like I have make wpf form, I need to add in tab control collection just like when we open wpf form in VS 2010 and it is open in Tab MDI form and different forms are showing in different tab.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use Forms to put n Tabpages. Use UserControls instead. You can put them there with the designer.